# In what sense do Presbyterians consider Christ's sacrifice "perfect"?

Tags: soteriology, reformed-theology, presbyterianism, sanctification

This question concerns in part the following quote heard regularly by Presbyterian Pastors:

> “Catholics deny the sufficiency of Christ’s redemptive work on the cross and by doing so, forfeit their salvation.”

The Idea is explained in the following terms:

> Christ's sacrifice was perfect, and nothing we can do, not works, not anything, can save us.  (Which a Catholic believes) but Catholics have to “DO” things, (as explained by many Pastors): doing Christ in the Eucharist, doing other Sacraments, doing works of Mercy, doing intercessory prayer, doing the Mass each and every week, fasting, alms giving and Prayer.

The idea that Catholics “DO” these graces instituted by Christ rather than “Receiving” them, seems to dominate the thinking of many Presbyterian brethren.

According to Presbyterians, what would be more perfect, and on what Biblical basis do they justify their choice?

1. (Presbyterian Position)That Christ's Good works cover the sins of men with his sacrifice to the father, So that he no longer sees the the sinful nature of the Person, but rather sees the righteousness of the Son, and we are sanctified by that covering (No Actual Change to the Believer Is necessary after acceptance through faith), or,
2. That Christ actually does more than cover up our sins by the meritorious actions of the Son, but provides for us a Church with Sacraments, Graces for us to  help work out our salvation in fear and trembling, to actually increase our sanctity in a fallen world, to avoid the temptations of the flesh and not just to cover up our sinful nature, but to actually change and become sanctified by his Grace (Actual Change to the Believer is necessary after baptism).

Comment: @Caleb Thank you for your edit, I believe that you addressed the essence of my question in a way that I seem to be unable to do.  I envy your talent.

Comment: The position listed as the Presbyterian position isn't an accurate depiction of the Presbyterian position. In addition, it seems a very strange question to say "which do Presbyterians think is more right, the Presbyterian position or the not-Presbyterian position?"

Comment: @Marc that is an imaginary situation. Reformed Protestants do not believe it is possible to be saved and not undergo sanctification.

Comment: @curiousdannii  I believe I understand that, however, some facet of that process is not completed at the moment they are saved.  Surely you must agree with that, as the WMC states, sanctification continues.  The Church assures that when a person is baptized they are sanctified, 100%.  So the statement I would agree is true.

Comment: The RCC may claim that baptism results in immediate sanctification, but both the Bible and plain evidence of the eyes shows that this is not true. Otherwise every Catholic would be living a perfect, sinless life.

Comment: @birdie. It’s an initial state,  this question is not about Catholic teaching.

Comment: At some point, is someone going to answer this question, perhaps as a frame challenge pointing to the or misunderstandings embedded in the question?  If this question is not salvageable as is, then some VtC's are in order.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  the essential element is that some Reformed pastors claim Catholics are hell bound because we deny the sufficiency of Christ’s Perfect sacrifice.  An explanation as to how his claim, their version of perfection, is biblically Gods,  a covering rather than changing, should be easy.  As for me, I believe in a powerful God capable of more than the reformation allows.  All have been saved, not a few individuals predestined but all, with free will to persevere.

Comment: @Marc Might that be worth including in the question or was that part already edited out?   *Reformed pastors claim Catholics are hell bound because we deny the sufficiency of Christ’s Perfect sacrifice*

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Forfeit Salvation = Hell Bound.  These Reformed Pastors, have pronounced judgement on me and my Church.   With a few Caveats,  for example, "They may have faith in Jesus Alone" for their salvation".   Which I think is the position of Catholics.  Believing however in the teachings of the Church, as for example I do without question, forfeits the faith I have in Christ.   It's a slippery slope, I'd hate to be the one condemning another Christian.

Comment: @Birdie *The RCC may claim that baptism results in immediate sanctification, but both the Bible and plain evidence of the eyes shows that this is not true. Otherwise every Catholic would be living a perfect, sinless life* False logic, since the RCC is not a "once saved always saved" denomination. Due to free will, the RCC holds that one can still make the (poor) decision to turn away from God, and only by turning back to God (Repentance) can hope for salvation return.  As I did with a few Reformed questions, you brought partial understanding to that comment.

Comment: Thanks KorvinStarmast. Does not 100% sanctification, while in effect, result in a sinless life?